# margin datatable increased by itself after hiding / showing columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, datatable, datatables

margin table data increased by itself after hiding / showing columns.

This result before show/hide column.
[image]

after, I show/hide 10++times
[image]

Datatable css set default

```
table.dataTable {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

It start from 5 it is incremented by 1 for every show or hide. after I many click finally no one stop it
[image]

my script

```
var table = $('#table-result').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        dom: 'Blfrtip',
        buttons: [          
          {
            extend: 'collection',
            text: 'Export',
            buttons: [
                'copy',
                {
                  extend: 'excel',
                  title: titleExport
                },
                {
                  extend: 'csv',
                  title: titleExport
                },
                {
                  extend: 'pdf',
                  title: titleExport
                }
            ]
          }
        ],
        rowReorder: true,
        columnDefs: [
            { orderable: true, className: 'reorder data-table-custom-font', targets: 0 },
            { orderable: true, className: 'reorder data-table-custom-font', targets: 1 },
            { orderable: false, className: 'data-table-custom-font', targets: '_all' }
        ]
      });
```

and this script show/hide column

```
  $('button.toggle-vis').on( 'click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();           
            // Get the column API object
            let column = table.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );
            console.log($(this).attr('data-column'))  
            // Toggle the visibility
            column.visible( ! column.visible() );
              
          } );
```

Thank you. Tell me if you want something more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Answer set style width: 100%

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped hover" id="table-result" style="width:100%">
```